# php filesize returning stat failed error

Tags: php, operator-keyword, filesize

I'm calling the following:

```
while ( (!file_exists('./download/ah141090676723_100.jpg')) || (filesize('./download/ah141090676723_100.jpg') == '1359') ) { code that retrieves a remote file and writes it to '/ah141090676723_100.jpg'  }
```

... and getting a "filesize(): stat failed for ./download/ah141090676723_100.jpg" error.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that the remote server is flaky, and sometimes returns a garbage response (which is always 1359 bytes long).  So, I want to check to see if either A) the file doesn't exist (first run through), or B) the file equals garbage (1359); if either is true, attempt to grab and write the file.  Rinse and repeat until we get something that's not garbage.

The code actually seems to be working -- the file is retrieved and written, and I haven't had any garbage responses get through this loop -- but the error mystifies me.  I thought it might be that on the first run-through, the file doesn't exist, so filesize is throwing this error.  But the "||" operator should be preventing that second evaluation on the first run-through... right?

I should mention that I'm calling "clearstatcache();" inside the loop, after the retrieval/write.

Any help appreciated!

Scott

Comment: check out this posts: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/156142-solved-warning-filesize-stat-failed/

Comment: that does appear to be the root of the problem; I noticed that when the file already exists, the error isn't thrown.  So when the file doesn't exist, it's "not writeable".  But the question still remains: shouldn't "||" prevent it from getting to that part of the code?

Comment: All these years later, I think I understand what's going on.  Sorry for thread necro. I always thought that PHP would step through the script in logical fashion, and only stop if it hit an error -- which it wouldn't, under this theory, because the double-OR operator ("||") prevents it from getting to filesize() if file_exists() fails.  But that's not how PHP works.  At runtime, it parses the entire script first, and *then* executes it.  That's why a misplaced comma in a section of your script that is otherwise unreachable will terminate the script in an error.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
while ( file_exists('./download/ah141090676723_100.jpg') && filesize('./download/ah141090676723_100.jpg') == 1359)
```

as `file_exists` is always required. `filesize()` returns "stat failed" when a file does not exist or is not readable.